# How to make chocolatey install python2 into custom path?

Tags: python, chocolatey

I'm installing Python 2.7.11 using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org), which installs into `C:\tools\python2`:

```
choco install python2 -y
```

Is there any way I can get Python to install into `C:\Python27` instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, override the [install arguments](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsInstall#options-and-switches) -

`choco install python2 -y -o -ia "'/qn /norestart ALLUSERS=1 TARGETDIR=c:\Python27'"`

Alternatively you can create a Python27 folder and it will install there.

Note that is determined by reading through the chocolateyInstall.ps1 script - https://chocolatey.org/packages/python2#files