# How to install Python3 to custom path using Chocolatey?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chocolatey

I'm installing Python 3 with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), which installs into `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3`:

```
> choco install python3
```

Is there any way I can get Python3 to install into `C:\Python35` instead?

I´m aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581991/how-to-make-chocolatey-install-python2-into-custom-path) which is related to Python 2 ... but here a different package is used thus the answer there does not help in this case.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34581991/18475

Comment: @ferventcoder: As I said I am aware of it ;-)    But the answer there does not work for python3 package - I have tried it.

Comment: The general idea is the same, you pass arguments through Chocolatey. Yes, the exact command arguments are different, as one would expect for different installers. It might be surprising to some that Python2 and Python3 have differences in the installers though. :)

Comment: UPDATE: `> choco install python3` now installs to C:\Python35 by default.

Answer (score 12):

There is a possibility to override `--installargs` like this:

```
> choco install python3 -y --override --installarguments "'/quiet  InstallAllUsers=1 TargetDir=c:\Python35'"
```

You might see some (access denied) errors (guess Python 3.5.1 Package is broken) but overall it seems to work.

I recommend to create your own Package as there is a newer Python version 3.5.2 which is not in the public package feed on [chocolatey.org](https://chocolatey.org/packages/) yet

Comment: Or, you could help with getting the Python package that is on the Community Feed working.  The package source files are on GitHub, and we (I), would welcome any help that you could offer.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I just followed this [tutorial](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2012/07/02/a-simple-tutorial-create-and-publish-chocolatey-packages/), I changed version `3.5.1` to `3.5.2`. And in `chocolateyInstall.ps1` I changed five lines:
4.`$url = 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2.exe'`, 
5. `$url64 = 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-amd64.exe'`, 
6. `$version = '3.5.2'`, 
9. `$partialInstallArgs = '/quiet /passiv InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir='`, 14. `$installArgs = $($partialInstallArgs + '"' + $installPath + '"')`

Comment: Sorry but the formating in comment is terrible ... can´t get it better :(

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.8.2 at least, all you can do is change the registry yourself before installing. For instance type this:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath /ve /d C:/Python38 /f
```